# Electron/positron annihilation lines in astrophysics

Tags: soft-question, astrophysics, antimatter, gamma-rays

I have a reasonable understanding of electron/positron annihilation, in that it is a collision between a pair of particles, one matter and one antimatter, that generally produces gamma radiation. However, I do not understand how this concept can be applied in astrophysics. In particular, what are annihilation lines?

Comment: Annihilation lines are emission [spectral lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line) caused by the radiation emitted during an annihilation process.

Comment: Have  look at [this article](http://smsc.cnes.fr/INTEGRAL/lien3_res.htm) for a nice summary of the status of electron-positron annihilation line astronomy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annihilation lines are [spectral lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line) caused by the collision of particle-antiparticle pairs. In the case of $e^-e^+$, the emission is at 511 keV.

[image]
([source](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1307.4198) (arXiv link))

However, because it is caused by a collision of particles, rather than an absorption-emission of a photon, the peak is [Doppler broadened](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_broadening). This means that the peak is spread out over a few keV, rather than a very sharp feature only at 511 keV, as an emission spectra would be. This effect is true for all annihilation lines, not just $e^-e^+$.

The galactic plane is a hotspot for the 511 keV line, but we're not really sure (as far as I know, at least) what is the source for the positrons.

[image]
([source](http://isdc.unige.ch/integral/gallery.cgi?SCIENCE))

Some heavy elements can produce positrons in supernova nucleosynthesis (e.g., the [${}^{56}{\rm Ni}$ chain](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114880/no-tremendous-neutrino-flux-for-snia/114901#114901)). It's also possible that [low-mass X-ray binaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_binary#Low-mass_X-ray_binary) can produce positrons via pair-production in outflows. Another possible source could be [dark matter annihilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Indirect_detection_experiments). As far as I know, no *single* source has declared as "the" source for galactic positrons.

Comment: Could Hawking radiation from the supermassive black hole in the center be the cause of this hot spot?

Comment: @JanDvorak: [It's been proposed](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0503267), but I don't believe that it's been widely accepted.